# R: Function to Iteratively Impute\Back out Missing Values

Tags: r, loops, imputation, cross-reference

I am a long-time forum lurker and a first-time poster. I'm sorry in advance for any deficiencies in my post. This is a rather complicated one.

Description:
I have a Frankenstein dataset gathered from a variety of sources. It contains an inconsistent set of firm ID variables, 18 in total. Let's say I have 5 observations for a firm; I may have 2, 2, 10, or 16 of the identifiers. There is some overlap; the rest are missing (`NA`). I want to back out the missing IDs, so I ideally have 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, or perhaps 16, depending on the coverage I have for each firm.

Problem Description:
Now, this is a panel dataset, which adds an additional layer of complexity. Firms merge, move, and change legal state over time. Not all ID variables will treat these the same, so the ID variable's ID code might change depending on the observation time. I want to filter these cases out because I cannot be as confident of the correct ID to use.

Approach:
I have attempted to loop through the data for each variable (assuming I may pick a few additional matches while filling in the blanks). I group observations by each ID Variable and identify how many distinct observations each variable has. If there is more than 1 distinct observation for any corresponding ID variable, I assume there is a conflict. If there is only 1, I assume there are no conflicts and seek to fill in the missing values. However, my code does not seem to loop correctly, missing potentially imputable data.

```
Sample Data:

### Not ID 1 should be imputable while ID 2 should not
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, NA, 2, NA, 2, 2, 2)
ID_Variable_1 = c(10, 10, NA, 20, 20, 20, 19, 18),   
ID_Variable_2 = c(NA, 8, 8, 16, 16, 16, NA, NA),   
ID_Variable_3 = c(NA, 8, 8, NA, 10, NA, NA, NA)   
ID_Variable_4 = c(A10, NA, NA, NA, NA, B12, B12, B12)
```

```
Current attempt:
### Extract vector of variables names
column_vector <- names(data) 

### Set Function to impute data
Impute_missing_data <- function(data, column_vector){   

#### Back-up data
temp_data <- data  

#### Loop through each variable
for (i in column_vector) {

#### Identify unique ID combinations, filter out those which contain conflicts
imputation_candidates <- temp_data %>%       
group_by_at(vars(i)) %>%       
summarise(across(everything(), ~ n_distinct(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%       
filter(if_all(-i, ~ . <= 1), .preserve = TRUE)

#### Copy vector of IDs with imputable data
imputation_applying <- imputation_candidates\[\[i\]\] 

#### Update temporary data with imputable data. As all IDs are the same update based on the first non-NA
temp_data <- temp_data %>%       
group_by_at(vars(i)) %>%       
mutate(across(everything(), ~ ifelse(.x %in% imputation_applying & is.na(.), first(.x[!is.na(.x)]), .x))) %>% ungroup()   
}   

#### Return updated data
return(temp_data) 
}
```

```
Desired Output:
data_temp <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, NA, 2, NA, 2, 2, 2)
ID_Variable_1 = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 20, 20, 20, 19, 18),   
ID_Variable_2 = c(8, 8, 8, ,12, 16, 16, 16, NA, NA),   
ID_Variable_3 = c(8, 8, 8, NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, NA)   
ID_Variable_4 = c(A10, A10, A10, NA, NA, NA, B12, B12, B12)
```

Comment: Considering your sample data can you please add a desired output to your post?

Comment: Hi @AndreWildberg, thank you for the comment. I have attached the desired output above. I'm seeking to output an updated data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data %>% 
    rownames_to_column()%>%
    rows_patch(filter(fill(., everything(), .direction = 'downup'), ID == 1))%>%
    column_to_rownames()

Matching, by = "rowname"
  ID ID_Variable_1 ID_Variable_2 ID_Variable_3 ID_Variable_4
1  1            10             8             8           A10
2  1            10             8             8           A10
3  1            10             8             8           A10
4  2            20            16            NA          <NA>
5 NA            20            16            10          <NA>
6  2            20            16            NA           B12
7  2            19            NA            NA           B12
8  2            18            NA            NA           B12
```

Comment: Hi Onyambu,

Thank you for the solution. It is very elegant. It would solve the issue with the example data I have given, but I'm trying to translate it into a more complex setting.

Could something like: 
for(vector_of_IDs in firm_data)
  patched_data <- gappy_data %>% 
  arrange({{vector_of_IDs}}, rowname) %>%
  filter({{vector_of_IDs}}) %>% 
  group_by({{vector_of_IDs}}) %>%
  rows_patch(filter(., fill(., everything(), .direction = 'downup'), {{vector_of_IDs}})) %>%
  ungroup()

be adapted? to handle thousands of ID values

Comment: Thank you, btw!

 It took me a while to understand why you used .direction = 'downup'. I tried to implement this yesterday but was unable to. It was beneficial, as most gaps are in the middle of my dataset due to a COVID-19 interruption.

Comment: Why use `forloop` when you are using `tidyverse`? I do not understand. With tidyverse, no for-loop required

Comment: @SamDeegan updown direction is to ensure the filling is to ensure variables 2 and 3 are filled. please read the documentation.

Comment: Hi @Onyambu, I don't use for loops or purr often. I just find the syntax easier to evaluate when running into problems, and the speed gains from purr aren't significant with the number of observations I typically have.

Comment: Why am I using it for a loop? None of the column IDs are complete, and the observations were not recorded in any particular order; all feature some NAs. 

There may be an observation for ID 3 between ID 1 and 2, and I don't want to misattribute it to ID 1 or 2 by mistake.

I want to patch for known values of ID first. Then, proceed to known the values of ID_Variable_2 and group them from that perspective and patch. That way, I can avoid misclassifying ID 3 as ID 1 or ID 2.

Comment: When I try to adapt your suggested code, it seems to overpatch the data. It essentially removes all NAs in the data, which should not be possible due to the level of missingness and a small number of observations for some firms. 

So it is certainly on the right path an moved me closer to the solution, but not quite there yet. I upvoted your answer btw. It just won't show till I reach 15 reputation.

Comment: @SamDeegan does the solution provided work on the example give? I believe so. You should consider providing another example where the solution given fails. For now i do not know how to help beyond this solution